# Bridging-Header.h file and error "use undeclared types..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, bridging-header

i install Podfile in my app, and run it from my file .xcworkspace. My project is a Swift project but the pod installed are in ObjectC. 
I create myApp-Bridging-Header.h and add in it:

```
#import "SignalR.h"
#import "RockSocket.h" 
...
```

then open target>BuildSetting and add the path for the bridgingFile in SwiftCompiler-CodeGeneration>Object-C BridgingHeader.
I build the project and it's work fine, but in my ViewConytoller file when i create:

```
var connection:SignalR = SignalR()
```

i have the error "use undeclared type 'SignalR'.

I read some question but i don't solve my problem. Please can you help me??

EDIT 
I can't use SwiftR because it's write in JavaScript code and Jquery library, and i can't use it This is the screenshot of my bridging file. [image]

and this is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
pod 'SocketRocket', '0.3.1-beta2'
pod 'SignalR-ObjC', '2.0.0.beta1'
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks fir your answers.

Comment: I assume that you wrote `#import`, not `import`, in the bridging header file?

Comment: So it's should be `Signalr` or `SignalR`?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when i wrote the message.. I edit the post

Comment: did you try specifying `use_frameworks!` in your podfile

Comment: This is my pod file:
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
pod 'SocketRocket', '0.3.1-beta2'
pod 'SignalR-ObjC', '2.0.0.beta1'

Comment: I tried to use : "use_frameworks!" in Podfile, and it works fine. ThankYou @uchiha

Comment: Hello. If you solved your issue, you can select ("accept") an answer that helped you, or add an answer yourself - but please do not modify the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a swift wrapper provided for SignalR-ObjC called SwiftR, so you will have to do the follwing in your Pod file

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftR'
```

checkout the link here https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR

Answer (score 0):

In bridging header file you can write something like :-

```
#import "fileName.h"
or
#import "<filename/fileName.h>"
```

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, i used:

    #import "SignalR.h"

and try also:

    #import <SignalR-ObjC/SignalR.h>

but it doesn't work

Comment: Go to swift compiler-code generation and check your bridging header file...and also take sacreen shot of your xcode where your bridging header file is showing and upload here...so i will get your actual problem